# Android : "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined" error

Tags: android

I found the code for building some inputboxes and they are alright, but in this code it just doesnt work:

```
View.OnClickListener handleOnClick(final TextView textview) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(editOn==1){
                textview.setText("neuer Text");

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                alert.setTitle("Hinzufügen");
                alert.setMessage("Name des neuen Eintrags");

                final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  String entryInput = input.getText().toString();
                  loadUp(entryInput,"0","1.1.2000");
                  }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  }
                });


            }
        }
    };
}
```

It says, that "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"
Whenever i try to insert something in ".. new AlertDialog.Builder(**this**); , then i dont have any errors. I know, that "this" has to refer to something. When i used this code snippet on a menuitem, it works well, but i want to use it whenever i activated my edit button (thats what if(editOn==1) means) and click on a textview. This is kind of confusing i think, but i hope someone out there understand what i need and may help me !

Comment: Did you check what kind of arguments this constructor needs? What I see in the docs is that it takes Context - public AlertDialog.Builder (Context context) - so you should pass as an argument at least instance of a class which derives from Context.

Comment: I don't understand that to be honest...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are trying to send a clickListener instance to `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Try to send your activity's instance. For example if your activity name is `MainActivity` thy this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

or:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
```

**Edit:** To show an `AlertDialog` use its `show()` method:

```
AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
dialog.show();
```

[See docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context%29)

Comment: I have terrible problems with understanding the docs.. Your examples don't work btw :/

Comment: I guess you also forgot to use its show method. See my edited answer.

Comment: @besplash: but it does answer the basic problem in your code. Your this-pointer points to whatever class you're in at the moment, and that is an OnClickListener, which is not of Context type. So as aegean says, you need to reference the surrounding Activity class. You do that by asking for the relevant class by name and using its this-pointer. (E.g. MainActivity.this if that's what it's called.)

Comment: Again I did a simple problem.. I tried to use MainActivity on my own, because i thought that could be the problem, but as it didnt fix my problem i was confused.. The edited answer was the actual problem. I copied the code from another part of my program and forgot to show the Dialog. My fault, sry :D

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but maybe someone will find that useful!  :)

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(((MainActivity ) getActivity()));
        builder.setMessage( "No connectivity").setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```