# Cannot use this in a static context

Tags: java, android

having problem on below coding.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
```

the this having error, please help me have a look.

```
import java.io.File;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


        public static boolean isPhoneRooted() {

            // get from build info
            String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;
            if (buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys")) {
              return true;
            }

            // check if /system/app/Superuser.apk is present
            try {
              File file = new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk");
              if (file.exists()) {

                  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")

                    .setPositiveButton("OK", 

                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {     

                       @Override

                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       }

                      }).show();

              }
            } catch (Throwable e1) {
              // ignore
            }

            return false;
          }
}
```

Comment: do you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19938087

Comment: You cannot reference instance variables from static methods.Pass the context as a parameter to the method

Comment: so i should how ? can give me a correct answer ? i trying to check the phone is rooted or not

Comment: Like I said pass the context to isPhoneRooted method from wherever you are calling and use that context instead of "this". You can get the application context by getApplicationContext() method

Comment: can give me correct answer ? i dun understand, i am new in android develop

Comment: i just delete the static, then can work ady, but still cant display the alert

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public static boolean isPhoneRooted() {
  ...
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  ....
}
```

is explicitly not allowed.

Because the method is a [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) method and not an [instance](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/303430/what-is-instance-method) method, *this* doesn't actually exist (because `this` is an actual instance of a thing).

This is real basic stuff, you should probably read up on it.  [Here's](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html) a link comparing the two.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `public static boolean isPhoneRooted()` to `public static boolean isPhoneRooted(Context context)` and replace the code using `this` keyword with the `context` parameter of the method. And call the `isPhoneRooted();` method as `isPhoneRooted(this);`