# show alert dialog through button android

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to show an alert dialog when the user click a button

```
    Previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder answerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        }
    });
```

but I got an error in this line

```
            AlertDialog.Builder answerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

which said

```
 The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined
```

anyone know how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: Can you upload the full code of this activity ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937898/android-the-constructor-alertdialog-buildernew-view-onclicklistener-is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlertDialog` gets `Context` in the `Constructor` but you used `this` inside your onClickListenner. Instead you should write `YourActivity.this`

```
 Previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder answerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is your anonymous OnClickListener inner class. Use `MyActivity.this` instead (replace MyActivity with the name of the activity).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an object of `Context` to the `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor and `View.OnClickListener` does not extend `Context`

Change

```
AlertDialog.Builder answerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder answerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

as `Activity` extends `Context`

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` is your `View.OnClickListener` interface implementation.

Try this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder answerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
```

Where `YourActivity` is your Activity's name