# Unable To Pass Context From Main Activity to AsyncTask to Display AlertDialog - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm attempting to display an alertDialog using onPostExecute / AsyncTask (it it's own class outside my ActivityMain.java) however I'm getting an error stating "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(AsyncTask) is undefined."

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(FunctionResult result) {
    if(result != null) {
        listener.callback(result);
    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(c, "text", 1000).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        AsyncTask.this);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

After researching the issue I found this:

[Android : "The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937898/android-the-constructor-alertdialog-buildernew-view-onclicklistener-is)

Based upon the answer provided there it appears I am not passing the context correctly from ActivityMain to my AsyncTask class.

I tried implementing:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMain.this);
```

As well as this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

How might I pass the context correctly to avoid this error?

Comment: you can pass it to the constructor of asynctask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Raghunandan said, just pass it in the constructor

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<...,..., FuncionResult> {
    Context mCtx;

    MyTask(Context ctx) {
        mCtx = ctx;
    }
    ...
   protected void onPostExecute(FunctionResult result) {
       ...
       Toast.makeText(mCtx, "text", 1000).show();
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    mCtx);
       builder.show();
   }
}
```

Then you need to be careful to cancel the task if the activity is destroyed (or better paused) so to avoid leakage and notifications to the wrong activity/context

Comment: I'm getting a Fatal Error / NPE at my AlertDialog - did I miss something? http://pastebin.com/0sh7U96J

Comment: How did you create the task? From your Activity it should be something like `new MyTask(this)` . If you have something like `new MyTask(null)`, that is wrong

Comment: try {
      asyncResponse = new asyncTask().execute().get();
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Does that seem like it should work - or do you have any better ideas? :)

Comment: No, that is a bad idea and it won't work. Could you post the code where you create the task? (where you use the 'new' keyword for the task)

Comment: Also code where you declare the task class might help